# jQuery for loop every third

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it only every third when I change `i = 0` to `i = 1` but then I don't get all results.

```
$.getJSON('search.php', {q: query, ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
    var options = '';  
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        if(i % 3 == 0) {
            // every third
        } else {

        }
        $("#profile-search-results").html(options);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry... not clear... what are you trying to do... what is `j`... what do you mean by every third... do you want elements at indexes `3, 6, 9...` etc

Comment: try to check `for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 2) {` instead

Comment: I think the problem is the `if` condition is satisfied for the first element... it is because the index is starting from 0... `0 % 3` is 0.... so the indexes you are looking for are `2, 5, 7....` etc

Comment: Thanks Arun. It works :)

Comment: Please correct your question... how could "change i = 1 to i = 1" do anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think what are trying to do is to get elements at indexes `3, 6, 9...` etc but your condition is executed for first, fifth, eighth... etc elements.

The problem is your loop is starting with `0`, so `0%3` will return 0... since the element index in jQuery starts with `0`, what you need is elements at indexes `2, 5, 8,...` etc. So you should check for `reminder 3 == 2`

```
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 2) {

        // every third

    } else {



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`%` is [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

```
0 % 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2
6 % 3 = 0
7 % 3 = 1
...
```

So what you have is normal.